azure ai studio - indexing problem (ai search)
Through the web interface of ai.azure.com  I created all the necessary services such as azure ai studio with project, storage account, open AI, AI search, etc. And I connected all the services to a private endpoint.
The problem arose only when indexing files in Ai search if it is connected to a private endpoint I get error. If it is public, then everything works fine.
Has anyone encountered this problem?
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/ieQvTJj8.png)    [enter image description here]
step of ml pipeline - Creating Azure AI Search Index - Data ingestion failed
File "/azureml-envs/rag-embeddings/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azureml/rag/tasks/update_acs.py", line 131, in create_search_index_sdk
    if acs_config["index_name"] not in index_client.list_index_names():
  File "/azureml-envs/rag-embeddings/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/core/paging.py", line 123, in __next__
    return next(self._page_iterator)
  File "/azureml-envs/rag-embeddings/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/core/paging.py", line 75, in __next__
    self._response = self._get_next(self.continuation_token)
  File "/azureml-envs/rag-embeddings/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/search/documents/indexes/_generated/operations/_indexes_operations.py", line 502, in get_next
    raise HttpResponseError(response=response, model=error)
azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: Operation returned an invalid status 'Forbidden'
 (update_acs.py:467)
[2024-10-09 16:24:22] ERROR    azureml.rag.update_acs.update_acs - ActivityCompleted: Activity=update_acs, HowEnded=Failure, Duration=14317.24 [ms], Exception=HttpResponseError (activity.py:127)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/azureml-envs/rag-embeddings/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/azureml-envs/rag-embeddings/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)

[2024-10-09 16:24:10] INFO     azureml.rag.connections - Using User Identity for authentication. (connections.py:265)
[2024-10-09 16:24:10] INFO     azureml.rag.update_acs - Using Index fields: {
  "content": "content",
  "url": "url",
  "filename": "filepath",
  "title": "title",
  "metadata": "meta_json_string"
} (update_acs.py:309)
[2024-10-09 16:24:10] INFO     azureml.rag.update_acs - Ensuring search index shy-needle-jv648s7dcq99 exists (update_acs.py:127)
_AzureMLOnBehalfOfCredential.get_token succeeded
[2024-10-09 16:24:15] ERROR    azureml.rag.update_acs.update_acs - ActivityCompleted: Activity=update_acs, HowEnded=Failure, Duration=5516.44 [ms], Exception=HttpResponseError (activity.py:127)
[2024-10-09 16:24:16] ERROR    azureml.rag.update_acs - Failed to update ACS index (update_acs.py:429)
[2024-10-09 16:24:17] ERROR    azureml.rag.update_acs.update_acs - ServiceError: intepreted error = Rag system error, original error = Operation returned an invalid status 'Forbidden' (exceptions.py:124)
[2024-10-09 16:24:22] ERROR    azureml.rag.update_acs.update_acs - update_acs failed with exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/azureml-envs/rag-embeddings/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azureml/rag/tasks/update_acs.py", line 465, in main_wrapper
    map_exceptions(main, activity_logger, args, logger, activity_logger)
  File "/azureml-envs/rag-embeddings/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azureml/rag/utils/exceptions.py", line 126, in map_exceptions
    raise e
  File "/azureml-envs/rag-embeddings/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azureml/rag/utils/exceptions.py", line 118, in map_exceptions
    return func(*func_args, **kwargs)

I tried adding different access rights (roles) but it didn't help

I've had the same issue and just fixed it.
This is how:

Set the API key based access control for the search service in the azure portal

Set the admin key for the same resource in Azure Ai Studio
in the project settings > connected resources > choose the Azure AI Search (Cognitive Search) type resource, then edit. Check also if the target is set correctly!



